# Laravel change resource route uri

Tags: laravel, routes, uri

I have this route:

```
Route::resource('/main/d1', 'Dizainas1Controller');
```

by default create route is:

```
main/meniu/create
```

I want to change it like:

```
main/meniu/{id}/create
```

But only this route. Any possible ways?

Comment: so you want a sub resource? and that resource wouldn't create those URIs

Comment: I just want to pass an id to create route. I can send it, but it looks like main/meniu/create?14 <-- with question mark. I want to do it with slash

Comment: then don't use `Route::resource` and define the routes yourself; all `Route::resource` does is register 7 routes in a particular way (that you could register yourself)

Comment: yes, I know that I can define them all by one. But I wonder if there is a way, where I can use resource and just edit 1 route

Comment: tell it not to register the create route and define your own; you can tell the resource what to exclude ... otherwise you are looking at creating your own extended resource registrar to adjust how the 'create' route is defined

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it worked :)

```
Route::resource('/main/d1', 'Dizainas1Controller')->except(['create']);
Route::get('/main/d1/{meniu}/create', 'Dizainas1Controller@create')->name('d1.create');
```